# Clear cookies for a given iOS App

Tags: objective-c, ios

My App connects to a server and based on a cookie the server will issue a different response.

Is it no possible to programmatically clear the cookie store, so that the server will not recognize my App when it contacts the server the next time.

I gathered that clearing the Cookies in the Settings.app does only apply for cookies within Safari.

Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: You are aware of [`[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), yes?

Comment: Now I am. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay... following up on my earlier comment (and hoping this is the solution you are looking for), you probably want to utilize:

[`[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/deleteCookie:)

for each of the cookies for your site.

Comment: Please note that for some reason you can't call it with nil to delete all cookies..

Comment: @Michael can i clear the cookies in safari through an iOS application?

Comment: @GaneshKumar [unfortunately not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632294/is-it-possible-to-change-ios-safari-settings-programmatically)... Apple wants users to decide when cookies and browser history is cleared.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your changes to the NSHTTPCookieStorage to be retained, you'll also want to call off to

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To prevent this from slowing down your app, you may also want to call this on a background thread like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    //TODO: Cookie deletion logic here
});
```

EDIT:

If you just need to disregard cookies altogether for a given NSURLRequest, you can do so with:

```
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Where request is your instance of NSURLRequest.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Niralp it isn't possible to delete all cookies by passing nil to `deleteCookie:` on an instance of NSHTTPStorage. However, since iOS 8 there has been a `removeFromDate:` method that can be utilised to the same effect.

In Swift 4 this would be:

`HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0))`

That would remove all cookies in the app since the 1970 epoch which is likely suitable for most needs.

Comment: You can also use `Date.distantPast`