# Delete cookies after twitter login

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

I implemented login screen by using `twitter authentication` after successful login screen navigates to home screen its works fine. When I come back and clicks on `twitter login` it does not asks `credentials`. It directly `redirects` the app into home page. So please help me how to remove `cookies` or `session` of `twitter`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dealing with `NSHTTPCookieStorage` like in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026432/how-to-clear-cookies-for-specific-domain-in-ios?lq=1)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code...

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieList = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *x in cookieList.cookies) {
       //if ([[x valueForKey:@"domain"] isEqualToString:@".twitter.com"]) { 
      // Do your stuff
           [cookieList deleteCookie:x]; 
       //}
}
```

Read: [NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html)
and [NSHTTPCookie_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/index.html)

[Where are an UIWebView's cookies stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored)

[How to get completely logout from FHSTwitterEngine in Twitter Rest API v1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499999/how-to-get-completely-logout-from-fhstwitterengine-in-twitter-rest-api-v1-1)